# JavaFx choicebox event handler method doesnt change variable?

Tags: javafx

I'm new at javafx but I'm writing an app and I want my "to" value to change depending on which option is chosen in the choicebox but my current code always keeps it at 0..help? I want to be able to change the to depending on state

```
      public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
     double to=0;
       primaryStage.setTitle("ShCal");
     GridPane pane = new GridPane();
   ` pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
     pane.setHgap(10);
     pane.setVgap(10);
     pane.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
     Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 275);

     //button
     Button button=new Button("to");
     pane.add(button, 0, 3);

     //Pick state
     Label State=new Label("State");
     pane.add(State,0,0);
     //choicebox
     ChoiceBox<String> choicesBox=new ChoiceBox<>();
     choicesBox.getItems().addAll("NJ","NY");
     pane.add(choicesBox,1,0);
     //set default
     choicesBox.setValue(null);

     button.setOnAction(e->getChoice(choicesBox,to));




    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    }

    private double getChoice(ChoiceBox<String> choicesBox, double tx) {
          String state=choicesBox.getValue();
          System.out.print(tx);
          if(state=="NJ")
          {
             tx=10/100;
         }
           System.out.print(state);
         return tx;
         }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `to` value is of the primitive type double, defined in the scope of your `start` method. The method `getChoice` returns the new value, but you are not updating it.
Here are two approaches that you can try:
Define `to` as member:

```
private double to = 0;
private double getChoice(ChoiceBox<String> choicesBox) {
  String state=choicesBox.getValue();
  if(state=="NJ") {
    tx=10/100;
  }
}
```

However I personally would prefer a solution that is more inline with JavaFX: Define the `to` variable as member property:

```
private DoubleProperty to = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
private double getChoice(ChoiceBox<String> choicesBox) {
  String state=choicesBox.getValue();
  if(state=="NJ") {
    tx.setValue(10/100);
  }
}
```

Doing it this way you can then for example have a label displaying the value without the hassle of requiring to update it on each change:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.textProperty().bind(to.asString());
```

Comment: where did you declare the double property? in the start? also do you still need to declare tx in the getChoice  method's argument? I'm not sure why it wasnt updating, any material I can read?

Comment: No, the `DoubleProperty` is defined as a member on the class. With that setup you no longer need the `tx` parameter on the getChoice method. You can take a look at Oracles [binding tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/)